# Why <span> tag content does not get update when its data-plugin="counterup" is set

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have following HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div class="text-right">
        <h3 class="mt-1">$<span id="ValueCounter" data-plugin="counterup">58,947</span></h3>
        <p class="text-muted mb-1 text-truncate">Total Revenue</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Ajax to get actual value from DB and trying to update the same in JQuery ready function as under:

```
$().ready(function() {
        //alert("JQuery Working");
        //Get data from DB and update the value in Span
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_get_customer_bill_total.php",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                    cust_id:"1",                    
                },
            success: function( data ) {
                    $("#ValueCounter").html(Math.round(data)); //<= this has not effect
            }
        });
});
```

The value returned from DB does not get set in the `span` why and how to solve this?

If I set the value/content of `span` to `0` then the value gets updated. Again why and how to solve this?

```
<span id="ValueCounter" data-plugin="counterup">0</span>
```

But then the problem of setting content to `0` is that the value updated using Ajax does not count up. It just appears.

Comment: Most of the count up plugin is animated by updating the content of `span`. If you directly update the `span` with a value. It would not work. You may have a check on the documentation of your plugin to see if there is a API or function call to update the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the counter plugins that I have checked do not have support/API for updating values. Only API give is to abort counting animation.